Is stationarity always an requirement for Spearman correlation between two time-series?
I would like to know if time-series data always (in every case imagineable) has to be stationary before computing the Spearman correlation between two time-series. I subsequently explain my specific situation and wonder if I have to process my two time-series before correlating them, such as via taking the first difference for each time-series.
Theoretical background about my two time-series:
I have two time-series: A) colored in blue and B) colored in orange. Both time series have the same number of sampling points (818). A subject watched a movie during brain scanning. A) is data stemming from the auditory input of the movie, and B) is the reactivity to that input in the auditory cortex of the brain.
Computing the Spearman correlation between two time-series:

Spearman correlation computed on the raw time-series as depicted in the image:
The Spearman correlation between A) and B) is 0.61 before taking the first difference of each time-series.

Spearman correlation computed after taking the first difference of each time-series:
Next, I first applied the Augmented Dickey-Fuller (ADF) test to check the time-series’ stationarity.


Input before differencing: p-value = 0.14 (data is not stationary)
Input after differencing: p-value < 0.001 (data is stationary)

Brain before differencing: p-value = 0.09 (data is not stationary)
Brain after differencing: p-value < 0.001 (data is stationary)

The results show, following the ADF test, that both time-series lack stationarity before differencing them, and become stationary after taking the first difference for each time-series. When taking the first difference of each time-series, the correlation yields -0.044, eliminating any correlation between both time-series.
My understanding is that, from a pure statistical point of view, the relatively high correlation (0.61) without differencing both time-series is particulary driven by the non-stationary nature of both time-series A) and B).
However, I know that the non-stationary elements in time-series A), such as the big plateau in time points ~80 to ~190 stems from the input, and that the same plateau in time-series B), although slightly longer, is the actual reactivity of the brain that follows the auditory input. Thus, the two dynamics are not driven by an unknown third source.
Question:
Given the assumptions I made above are correct, would it still be necessary to difference both time-series before computing Spearman’s correlation? Phrased differently, is it invalid to compute Spearman’s correlation (or any kind of correlation, such as Pearson’s, Kendall’s, or difference correlation) before making both time-series stationary in my specific case?
If the estimation of a correlation between two time-series is invalid in the presence of non-stationarity, what other options do I have to quantitatively show that there is a clear correspondence between both observed time-series? (Given the fact that I lose the correlation after taking the first difference.)


Perhaps tangential point:  the brain reaction may correlate most highly with a lagged version of the auditory input -- I would try a lag of 200-600 milliseconds, if the data allow that.

It depends on what you mean by "a requirement". (You can certainly calculate such a correlation. The properties of the coefficient are potentially quite different when the series are non-stationary from when they are stationary; indeed even weaker circumstances may impact the properties.)

Can you be sure, and can you easily convince your audience, that no third variable is influencing both of these series?  If so, the undifferenced correlation becomes more credible.

rolando2, I am 100% certain (ok, let us say 99%) that the significant ups and downs in both dynamics (time-series) are not influenced by a third unknown variable. For example, the mentioned plateau around datapoints 80 to 190 is induced by music kicking in (in the movie) just within this time span. I lack the statistical knowledge to be certain of the following, but I feel that I "destroy" the original dynamics of input and brain by differencing both time-series, so that I would subsequently just correlate "noise" if that makes sense.

I think you are on the right track.

rolando2, thanks for your feedback. One further question: would it also be feasible to compute granger causality (GC) without first differenceing both time-series in my specific case? GC also formally requires that time-series are stationary. Probably I better create a new question for this question I guess, unless it is possible to answer it without further details.
